# First and Last Element of a Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, algorithm, list

i have a question about doubly linked lists. I cannot find any suitable explanation for my question in the internet. Maybe i am just to stupid to find the right question..

This is how a linked list should look when it is initialized:

```
[Head][Tail]
```

But will the actual Head and Tail Nodes still exist when i add Values to the List or will they be overwritten when i add values?

Should it look like this:

```
[Head][Value1][Value2][Value3][Value4][Tail]
```

or like this:

```
[Value1][Value2][Value3][Value4][Value5]
```

Comment: Head or tail are not separate nodes. We just point [VALUE1] as head and [VALUE5] as tail node.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow, please edit your question to follow [mcve], also some tips you can get at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), thanks in advance. 
btw previous comment is correct

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx IMO this kind of conceptual question doesn't require a MCVE. The question is perfectly clear to me as is.

Comment: @pkpnd yes, the question is clear, but it will be better to have there visibility of any effort, instead just the question, that was my point.

Comment: It’s not that you cannot have dummy nodes for head and/or tail. You may read about [sentinel nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node). For a doubly linked list you usually don’t have, though.

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx I don't know what you're on about, this question is 100% the way it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a list is initialized it's like:

```
[]
Head=null, Tail=null
```

After inserting Value1 it becomes

```
[Value1]
Head = Value1, Tail = Value1
```

After inserting Value2 it becomes

```
[Value1][Value2]
Head = Value1, Tail = Value2
```

You don't have seperate node for Head and Tail. Head and Tail are just references to existing Nodes. Hence real nodes are only the Value* nodes while Head and Tail are just references.

Answer (score 2):

You should design it so head and tail can be null when the list is empty and the list looks like this:

***[Value1][Value2][Value3][Value4][Value5]***